# Couldnt Match Integer With Double? - Creating a Rectangle

Tags: haskell

```
shapeToPic :: Shape -> Picture
shapeToPic (Line a b) = polyline [a, b]
shapeToPic (Rectangle a b) = rectangle a b
```

Shape is defined by

```
data Shape = Rectangle Side Side
       | Ellipse   Side Side
       | Polygon   [Point]
       | Line      Point Point
 deriving (Show)
```

Error I get:

> `<interactive>:55:41: error:
>       * Couldn't match type`(Integer, Integer)' with `Double'
>         Expected type: Side
>           Actual type: (Integer, Integer)
>       * In the second argument of`Rectangle', namely `(5, 7)'
>         In the first argument of`shapeToPic', namely
>           `(Rectangle (3, 3) (5, 7))'
>         In the first argument of`drawingOf', namely
>           `(shapeToPic (Rectangle (3, 3) (5, 7)))'

Kind of new to Haskell, I understand I need to put a 'Side' type as a rectangle needs 2 points, however, not sure what the problem is. I have 2 points? Any help with solving this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you made a typo and confused dot with comma?

```
let x = (1.1) :: Double -- type checks
let x = (1,1) :: Double -- same error
```

Comment: Where abouts exactly? And I should have stated that 
`shapeToPic (Line a b) = polyline [a, b]`
works fine. Its just the rectangle code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if `Side` is defined as a `Double`, and not as a pair. So, `Rectangle 13.45 12.32` would be OK, while `Rectangle (x1,y1) (x2,y2)` does not.

Apparently, a "rectangle" shape only contains width and height, but not the "origin point". This is weird, since lines and polygons, instead, do contain a origin point in the `Shape` type. This looks as a potential design inconsistency.

You should provide a definition for `Side` in your question, otherwise we can only speculate.

Comment: My bad! Thanks for your reply!
Side is defined by this:
`type Side = Double`

Comment: @goat So I guessed right, a rectangle is a pair of side lengths, not a pair of points, according to your definition of shape.